# Swap values of two map

Tags: java, collections

I'm a beginner,
I want to create a new map hm3 by using two old maps hm1 and hm2 and in that map I need value of second map as key and value of first map as value 
For example : if map hm1 is containing a1 as key1 and abc as value1 and it also containing a2 as key2 and xyz as value2 and there is another map hm2 which contains a1 as key1 and b1 as value1 and also containing a2 as key2 and b2 as value2 then in the map hm3 I need b1 as key1 and abc as value1 and b2 ans key2 and xyz as value2

```
    public class MapInterchange {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String, String> hm1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Map.Entry m1;
        hm1.put("a1", "abc");
        hm1.put("a2", "xyz");

        for (Map.Entry m : hm1.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(m.getKey() + " " + m.getValue());
        }

        HashMap<String, String> hm2 = new HashMap<String, String>();

        hm2.put("a1", "b1");
        hm2.put("a2", "b2");

        for (Map.Entry m : hm2.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(m.getKey() + " " + m.getValue());
        }

        HashMap<Object, Object> hm3 = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

        Iterator itr = ((Set<Entry<String, String>>) hm1).iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            hm3.put(((Entry) hm2).getValue(), ((Entry) hm1).getValue());
        }

        for (Map.Entry m : hm3.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(m.getKey() + " " + m.getValue());
        }

     }

    }


The exception I'm getting is : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.Set
    at com.sid.MapInterchange.main(MapInterchange.java:34)
```

Please provide the corrected code, I will be very thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast a HashMap to a Set of entries. Use the `entrySet` method.

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> itr = hm1.entrySet().iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String,String> entry = itr.next();
    hm3.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

EDIT: I'm not sure this code does what you want to do, but it overcomes your error. It's not clear what you are trying to swap.

If the mapping of the values is based on the keys, your code should be :

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> itr = hm1.entrySet().iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String,String> entry = itr.next();
    hm3.put(hm2.get(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue());
}
```

This assumes that all the keys of `hm1` appear in `hm2` (otherwise you'll have a `null` key in your output Map).

Comment: I want to create a new map and in that map I need value of second map as key and value of first map as value

Comment: @Siddharth But how do you determine which value of the first map is mapped to which value of the second map?

Comment: It does clear the exception but not solving my problem. I edited the question. Please try and help me out now.

Comment: @Eran, probably by the common key (`"a1"`, `"a2"`, etc.)

Comment: See if map hm1 is containing a1 as key1 and abc as value1 and it also containing a2 as key2 and xyz as value2 and there is another map hm2 which contains a1 as key1 and b1 as value1 and also containing a2 as key2 and b2 as value2 then in the map hm3 I need b1 as key1 and abc as value1 and b2 ans key2 and xyz as value2